# .htaccess redirect to root when file not found

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

i have a. .htaccess file which looks like below (ps not mine, i think it belongs to Joomla):

Now something or bad programming images link to "somefolder/folder/image.png" instead of "/somefolder/folder/image.png" (mind the / in the beginning. This would cause it to look from the directory its in upwards instead of the root.

How would i rewrite this so if the file is not found it tries to go to the file starting from the root of the site. Also, this should only do so for .css|.jpng|.png|.js

thanks for the help... btw the folder somefolder and its subfolder can be any name, it's not always the same folder name.

Yes i have checked other entries on SO, but they all didn't work for my exact problem...

```
##
# @package              Joomla
# @copyright    Copyright (C) 2005 - 2012 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license              GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
##

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On






## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.



## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

# RewriteBase /
RewriteBase /
## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for something within the component folder,
# or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

oh i thought this would do it, but it doesnt

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .*$ /%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why simply adding a `/` to the beginning of the request URI doesn't work is because the browser sees the relative URL, and *appends its own BASE to it **before** requesting it from the server*. That means by the time the rewrite engine sees it, it's already got a bunch of paths and/or folder in front of it. I don't think you should try to use mod_rewrite to undo what the browser is doing (and doing correctly). You need to fix the problem in the content. I'm assuming that making all the relative URLs in the content absolute is too difficult, more difficult than trying to get mod rewrite to brute force squeeze requests into existing folders, so one thing you can do is add this to the content's header:

```
<base href="/">
```

To change all your relative URLs to absolute ones.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteRule .*$ /%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```